# Custom Django Model that Returns Data to View

Tags: python, django

Let me point out that this is week #2 with Django - meaning i am a newbie. Goal: To use a custom model to retrieve data from a Postges DB and return this data to a view and then to a template within Django

settings.py

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'opengov_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'OGSDB',
        'USER': 'web_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin123',
        'HOST': '10.187.240.117',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

And here is what in within models.py:

```
    from django.db import models

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class data_model(models.Field):
    description = "return and create data objects for visulaizations"

    def __init__(self, days, action):
        self.days = days
        self.action = action

        if(self.action == ""):
            self.action = "inspections"

        print self.action
        getVioPoints(self.action, self.days)
    #end init

    def getVioPoints(self):
        #get points 
        if(self.action == "violations"):
            apendQuery = "where osha_violation_indicator is true"
        elif(self.action == "inspections"):
            apendQuery = "where osha_violation_indicator is false"
        else:
            apendQuery = ""

        from django.db import connections           
        conn = connections['opengov_db'].cursor()

        conn.execute("""
            select distinct a.estab_name, b.latitude, b.longitude, a.site_address, a.site_city, a.site_state, a.site_zip
            from osha_inspection a
            join latitude_longitude_lookup b on cast(a.activity_nr as text)= b.source_data_id
            """,apendQuery,"""
            and close_case_date >= now() - interval """,self.days,""" days'
            and b.latitude is not null; """)

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            print row['estab_name']

        return row
```

And finally, here is the views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.template import RequestContext

def index(request):
    # Obtain the context from the HTTP request.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    return render_to_response('map/index.html', {'title':'Home Page'}, context)
#end index
```

Issue:
The query in models.py is going to return a set of coordinate points and metadata associated with businesses. I want to loop through it, and return the data in the view so that i can pass it to the template file. The views.py file will need to be expanded to pull the data from models.py, but how is this done?

I have looked around and i know this is not the typical Django way of returning a DB object. But, there must be a way to return a recordset to a view without using what the Django tutorial gives you using SQLite 3. I could really use some guidance here. I have not found anything online describing how to do this in this way. Does that mean that you can't?

FYI: No errors being returned when loading the index.html file in the browser. Not sure how to validate if the data is being retrieved or not. I did try: *python models.py* and this is what is returned -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals, sql
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 22, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql import aggregates as base_aggregates_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/aggregates.py", line 9, in <module>
    ordinal_aggregate_field = IntegerField()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Any assistance would be most welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This whole approach makes no sense at all.

As you have already been told elsewhere, subclassing models.Field is utterly inappropriate. A field is part of a model, not a standalone thing, and doesn't make SQL queries by itself. If you really need to do it this way, subclass Model.

But I don't understand why you want to make any kind of class at all. Why not use the Django ORM? Or if you insist on doing it via raw SQL, why not make `getVioPoints` a simple standalone function that you can call, which returns the data? Since there's no state being stored - your class queries the db on instantiation and returns the data directly - there's no point in having a class at all.

(And your error is happening because you need to start the shell with `manage.py shell`, and then import your file. But it still won't work, you'll just get a different error.)

Comment: I am new to Django, so making model a class seemed like that was part to the normal convention for models based on the tutorial i found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/. How to you use the ORM with Postgres?

Comment: But you wouldn't subclass Field in any case, as I say. And there is no difference in using sqlite versus Postgres in the ORM, that's the whole point: it abstracts away the differences between db backends.

Comment: I appreciate your answers, but could you edit your answer and add a simple code example or provide a link that shows how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: How to simply return data from the database. This is very simple to do in other languages. Why is this so difficult to get a simple sample with postgres? I am going to be building a large JSON object and dynamically updating it with ajax. Right now, i just want to connect to the DB and return some data from a simple query.

Comment: It's not difficult, it's you that are trying your utmost hardest to make it difficult by doing weird things like subclassing models.Field. You have the simple query right there.  **Get rid of the class** and make `getVioPoints` a standalone function, with "action" and "days" parameters, which you can call in your view. There, done.